# Получить класс из webpack программно

Tags: javascript, webpack

Я делаю расширение для web.telegram.org/k/. Мне надо изменить некоторые из JavaScript функций, которые загружены в виде webpack. Но я не знаю, как получить доступ к этим функциям. Есть идеи?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык, для этого нажмите [edit] под самим вопросом

Comment: Разместите, пожалуйста, сюда код вместо картинки

Comment: Да собственно кода и нет. Картинка иллюстрирует структуру ресурсов веб-клиента Telegram, где отдельным блоком выделены модули, подгруженные в bundle webpack. Я не могу найти способ программным способом получить доступ к любой из функций (классов) в webpack.